How can I hide a file or folder using Ansible on Windows?
Is there a way to mark a file or folder as hidden using Ansible on Windows?
I've checked the win_file module,
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_file_module.html
but could not find an option to create hidden files.
I understand I can run a Powershell script,
but then to not litter my logs with "changed" marks I would then also need to check if an item is already hidden.
Is there an existing way using Ansible to create a hidden item, or make an existing item hidden, without needing to check if the item is hidden?

Anyone care to comment on the downvotes? Otherwise it's hard to ask a better question...

i think, asking how to set the hidden file mask is a standard task, the question imho should be updated to reflext, what you want to afford with this?

I indicate I know it's a standard task in Powershell, but am specifically looking for a way in Ansible to do this, without having to craft a check/set script myself. Is this also a "standard task" using Ansible on Windows? If so, an answer would be to point me to the module/manual that explains how it's done, because I've not been able to find it. What I want to achieve with this? I want to make a folder hidden such that users don't interact with it by accident.

this is not a protection. only access limitation can archive your problem.

I am sorry @djdomi, I don't follow. Could you perhaps write the comment in your native language (German?) such that I can run it through a translator? Thanks!

Ok, reproducing the short to long; hiding files does not protect against any kind of users. NTFS and refs support access limitation by users and groups. So far, it is the only true way and answer to your question. And that is the way you should go.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There does not seem to be a module which is able to change file or folder attributes. But there is one which can check it: ansible.windows.win_stat
So you could either first check with a task using the win_stat module and execute or skip the attribute changing task using a when: conditional or just execute one script using win_powershell and check for change yourself and handle it with the $Ansible.Changed variable as written in win_powershells notes.
While I would prefer last, since you could do everything in one single task rather then two, both would prevent you from filling your log with false changes.

How about changing or altering the access rights? Would it be possible?

Yes of course, there is a specific module for this purpose: win_acl. This would be easier and safer, if safety was a concern. But this seems not to be OPs objective.

With ACL, it will be possible to hide and protect files from standard users while still allowing access.

I think OP wants to set the file attribute "hidden". Afaik this is not possible with Ansibles win_acl module.
